# Cut long string

Tags: java

I have a potentially long string and need to cut it smart. Example below.
Given:

```
Very long string that is really too long to be placed on UI.
```

Cut to leave string not longer than `N` letters:

```
Very long string that is really too...
```

This should not split the words like:

```
Very long string that is real...
```

Is there any complete solution/library?

Comment: I am not familiar with Android programming, but couldn't you detect the white space nearest to the cutoff point of the long string?

Comment: I would just write it myself. Look like a couple of lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

I would try something like.

```
public static String truncate(String line, int maxLength) {
    if(line.length() < maxLength) return line;
    int pos = line.lastIndexOf(" ", maxLength-3);
    if (pos <= 0) pos = maxLength - 3; // no spaces, so just cut anyway
    return line.substring(0, pos) + "...";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `setEllipsize (TextUtils.TruncateAt where`). Documentation found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize%28android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizer to cut the string up by words using spaces and then just output the first few words.  This link has a great example:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class and call its static method. This method will prevent outofbounds errors and null pointer exceptions

public class SmartSubstring {

```
public static String smartSubstring(String str, int maxLength) {

    String subStr = str.substring(0);

    if (maxLength == 0) {
        return "";
    } else if (str.length() <= maxLength) {
        return str;
    } else {
        int i = maxLength;
        while (i >= 0) {
            while (str.length() < i) {
                i--;
            }
            if (str.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                subStr = str.substring(0, i);
                break;
            }
            i--;

        }
        return subStr;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = new String("Otomotopia is a very very long word that is "
            + "hard to contain in a mobile application screen");

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        String tester = SmartSubstring.smartSubstring(test, i);
        System.out.println(tester + tester.length());
    }
}
}
```